# Python Mapreduce running on duplicate data read from hbase

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have written a mapreduce code using python streaming(having only mapper function implementation) and used happybase to read from  Hbase.
When I am running a mapreduce code in 5 node distribution since the python streaming code is having a scan function which reads records from hbase and is distributed throughout the cluster all the mapper instances created are processing on the same data sets extracted/read from the hbase .

example:

```
for key, data in table.scan(row_start='1'):

    Somecompute( key, data)
```

Here if i have 100  rows in hbase all the mapper instances spawned in the cluster is processing same 100 records from hbase since it is executing the same mapper code in the distribution hence duplication.
My requirement is that m1 mapper should process 1 to 20 records,m2 mapper should process 21 to 40 records,m3 should process 41 to 60 etc....
How can i achieve this in python streaming using happy base?
Could anyone please help.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In happybase, using scan, `row_start` means **deciding start row key**.

so if start_rows are same, then results set will be same.

If you want to get the next set, You must set the row_start to last row-key of pre-result

Like below

1. 1st scan : `row_start=1` , `result=[1:101]`, `last_row=101` and `Somecompute(1 ~ 100)`
2. 2nd scan : `row_start=101` , `result=[101:201]`, `last_row=201` and `Somecompute(101 ~ 200)`
3. 3rd scan : ....

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: han058:Whatever you have mentioned is exactly my requirement,but how does the other mapper instance say m2 will know that it has to scan table for 101 to 201 records i.e the pre-results and m3 from 202 to n,  as my map reduce code i mention row_start starting from 1 and deploying the code.I have more than a million records in hbase table.